# discord.py | Edit role permissions

Tags: discord.py

So, I'm trying to do a command, called "bebr", which would give an administrator permission to the role, but I couldn't do it. Can you please help me with that? Server ID is 776512018009030686, and Role ID is 872111767709417473.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot needs to have the administrator permissions in order to grant them to other roles. The role the bot is modifying also needs to be lower in hierarchy. This code does the job on my test server:

```py
from discord import Role
from discord.ext.commands import command, Context

@command()
async def bebr(ctx: Context, role: Role):
    overrides = role.permissions
    overrides.administrator = True

    await role.edit(permissions=overrides)
    await ctx.send(f"Added administrator privileges to role {role}.")
```

When your bot doesn't have the administrator permission or has its role lower than the one it's trying to modify, it will throw a `Missing Permissions` error.

Comment: I copied that, changed "command" to "bot.command" and tried, but I got an error "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing."

Comment: Okay, your updated code worked! Thanks a bunch!